# Visnetwork shiny not working, - $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am working on shiny app where I need to create a network chart using visNetwork. 
While running the code I am getting following error-

Error in : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Stack trace (innermost first):
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$kolNetwork
     1: runApp

Below is my ui code-

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    #css to format the views
    tags$style(
      HTML("
          #filterRow>div{
           width: 140px;
              display : inline-block;
              margin-right: 15px;
          }
          .main-header{
              display:none;
          }
          .content{
               position: fixed;
               height: 100%;
               width: 100%;
               top: 0;
               left: 0;
               background: #fff;
               z-index: 1000;
          }
          .selectize-control.single .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input input{
                height: 22px !important;
           }
           ")
    ),

    #code for main view
    fluidRow(column(12,tags$div(style="height:10px;"))),
    fluidRow(column(12,
                    tags$div(id = "filterRow",
                             selectInput("countryFilter", "Country", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$country))), selected = "Select", multiple = F, selectize = T),
                             selectInput("specialtyFilter", "Specialty", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$specialty))), selected = "Select", multiple = F, selectize = T),
                             selectInput("sponsorFilter", "Sponsor", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$sponsor))), selected = "Select", multiple = F, selectize = T),
                             selectInput("kolFilter", "KOL", choices = "Select", selected = "Select", multiple = F, selectize = T),
                             actionButton("createNetwork", "Go", style = "margin-top: -2%; background-color :#3C8DBC; color: #fff; font-weight: 600; height: 40px; width: 110px;font-size: 20px;")
                    ))
            ),
    fluidRow(
      column(9, tags$div(style = 'height: 700px;', visNetworkOutput("kolNetwork"))),
      column(3, tags$div(style = 'height: 700px;', uiOutput("networkLegend")))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width=12,
        box(
          width = 12,title = "Influencer Details",solidHeader = T,status = "primary",collapsible = T, collapsed = F,
          DTOutput("kolNetworkTable"),
          tags$div(uiOutput("download"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Below is the server.R file

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  #update rest columns on selection in country column
  observeEvent(input$countryFilter, {
    if(input$countryFilter!="Select"){
      node_file <- filter(node_file, country %in% input$countryFilter & from_flag == "y")
      updateSelectInput(session, "specialtyFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$specialty))), selected = "Select")
      updateSelectInput(session, "sponsorFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$sponsor))), selected = "Select")
      updateSelectInput(session, "kolFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$id))), selected = "Select")
    }
    else if(input$countryFilter=="Select"){
      updateSelectInput(session, "specialtyFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$specialty))), selected = "Select")
      updateSelectInput(session, "sponsorFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$sponsor))), selected = "Select")
      updateSelectInput(session, "kolFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$id))), selected = "Select")
    }
  }, ignoreInit = T)

  observeEvent(input$specialtyFilter, {
    if(input$countryFilter!="Select"){
      node_file <- filter(node_file, country %in% input$countryFilter & from_flag == "y")
    }
    if(input$specialtyFilter!="Select"){
      node_file <- filter(node_file, specialty %in% input$specialtyFilter & from_flag == "y")
      updateSelectInput(session, "sponsorFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$sponsor))), selected = "Select")
      updateSelectInput(session, "kolFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$id))), selected = "Select")
    }
    else if(input$specialtyFilter=="Select"){
      updateSelectInput(session, "sponsorFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$sponsor))), selected = "Select")
      updateSelectInput(session, "kolFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$id))), selected = "Select")
    }
  }, ignoreInit = T)

  observeEvent(input$sponsorFilter, {
    if(input$countryFilter!="Select"){
      node_file <- filter(node_file, country %in% input$countryFilter & from_flag == "y")
    }
    if(input$specialtyFilter!="Select"){
      node_file <- filter(node_file, specialty %in% input$specialtyFilter & from_flag == "y")
    }
    if(input$sponsorFilter!="Select"){
      node_file <- filter(node_file, sponsor %in% input$sponsorFilter & from_flag == "y")
      updateSelectInput(session, "kolFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$kol))), selected = "Select")
    }
    else if(input$sponsorFilter=="Select"){
      updateSelectInput(session, "kolFilter", choices = c("Select", sort(unique(node_file[node_file$from_flag == "y",]$kol))), selected = "Select")
    }
  }, ignoreInit = T)


  #creating filtered dataset

  filteredData <- eventReactive(input$createNetwork, {
    temp <- copy(node_file[node_file$from_flag=="y",])

    if(input$kolFilter!="Select"){
      temp <- filter(temp, id %in% input$kolFilter)
    }

    if(input$sponsorFilter!="Select"){
      temp <- filter(temp, sponsor %in% input$sponsorFilter)
    }

    if(input$specialtyFilter!="Select"){
      temp <- filter(temp, specialty %in% input$specialtyFilter)
    }

    if(input$countryFilter!="Select"){
      temp <- filter(temp, country %in% input$countryFilter)
    }

  })

  # myNetworkChart <- function(edges, nodes){
  #   
  #   print("inside network chart function")
  #   
  #   output$kolNetwork <- renderVisNetwork({
  #     
  #     print("inside render visnetwork")
  #     
  #     edges <- data.frame(edges, width = edges$weight)
  #     
  #     nodes <- data.frame(nodes,
  #                         size = nodes$pageranks*1000+3,
  #                         title = nodes$id, borderWidth = 2,
  #                         color.highlight.background = "yellow",
  #                         shadow = list(enabled = TRUE, size = 10))
  #     
  #     #browser()
  #     
  #     visNetwork::visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%", height = "100%")
  #     print("after render visnetwork")
  #   })
  # }

  observeEvent(input$createNetwork, {
    #View(filteredData())

    edges <- subset(edge_file, from %in% filteredData()$id)
    nodes <- subset(node_file, id %in% edges$from | id %in% edges$to)

    output$kolNetwork <- renderVisNetwork({

      print("inside render visnetwork")

      edges <- data.frame(edges, width = edges$weight)

      nodes <- data.frame(nodes,
                          size = nodes$pageranks*1000+3,
                          title = nodes$id, borderWidth = 2,
                          color.highlight.background = "yellow",
                          shadow = list(enabled = TRUE, size = 10))

      #browser()

      visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%", height = "100%")
      print("after render visnetwork")
    })

    #myNetworkChart(edges, nodes)

  }, ignoreInit = T)

  #function to create network chart

}
```

Global.R only brings in the libraries and reads data file

Comment: Some dummy data would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Vaibhav have you been able to solve the problem ? I am having a similar case but cant find a solution